# How to pass/get Core Data context in SwiftUI MVVM ViewModel?

Tags: swift, core-data, mvvm, swiftui

**Context**

To performance operation on the Core Data object, the managed object context `managedObjectContext` is needed. The context is passed into View via the environment variable inside `SceneDelegate` when the project is generated with the "using Core Data" option checked (see below). A related question is [Why does Core Data context object have to be passed via environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960706/why-does-core-data-context-object-have-to-be-passed-via-environment-variable)

```
let contentView = MainView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

However, when I try to pass the `context` into the View Model, it complains the following

> Cannot use instance member 'context' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

```
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    
    // Computed property cannot be used because of the property wrapper
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel(context: context)
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext
}
```

Adding an `init()` to initialize the view model inside the view causes a different error which fails the build.

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report

```
    init() {
        self.viewModel = ViewModel(context: context)
    }
```

**Question**

So how can I use / get / pass the context inside the view model? What's the better way to get a context inside the view model?

Comment: You can for instance create an init() for your view and set it there but honestly, if you are using MVVM should you views have access to a NSManagedObjectContext instance?

Comment: the context reference from the `SceneDelegate` seems the only source, is there another way, I can get a context inside View Model?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61571960/8697793

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the complaining seems from `context` adding an `init()` does not resolve the error and a computed property cannot be used because the view model has a property wrapper

Comment: Ok, I missed that but if you indeed are using MVVM then the view model should be injected into rather than created in the view.

Comment: could you please explain to me how to do the injection?

Comment: You have a init method that takes a view model as argument in your view instead of instantiating the view model inside the view, this makes your code easier to test and you have weaker coupling between the two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is your scenario

```
let contentView = MainView(context: context)          // << inject
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel // << declare

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.viewModel = ViewModel(context: context)   // initialize
    }
}
```

Comment: The init function get called every time the view is presented. May be this view `MainVeiw` is only presented once, but in general this will cause ViewModel to be initialized more than once.

Comment: @Tony. Actually it is a nature of view model - to coexist with view, but if you want to inject dependency from outside, then just mail ViewModel with optional read-write property of context, so latter can be injected via property later, and inject that view model via MainView init arguments as well. DependencyInjection for everything!

Comment: Should be `@StateObject` and not `@ObservedObject` since it's created within the view.

Answer (score 1):

The CoreData context can get via the `AppDelegate` object.

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init() {
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}
```

REFERENCE, https://kavsoft.dev/Swift/CoreData/

Comment: If you are importing SwiftUI for your view model, you might as well get the context from the environment itself. Ruins the point of separating the UI and the VM, I think.